# How do you extract and validate a SAML token in the Authorization header using ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, wif, saml

I have a Silverlight app that requests a SAML token from an STS using the WSTrust implementation from the Identity Training Kit.

```cs
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    WSTrustClient wsTrustClient = new WSTrustClient(new WSTrustBindingUsernameMixed(), new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/SecurityTokenService/Service.svc/IWSTrust13"), new UsernameCredentials("user", "password"));
    wsTrustClient.IssueCompleted += new EventHandler<IssueCompletedEventArgs>(wsTrustClient_IssueCompleted);

    RequestSecurityToken rst = new RequestSecurityToken()
    {
        AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress("https://localhost/SilverlightApplication.Web")
    };

    wsTrustClient.IssueAsync(rst); 
}

private void wsTrustClient_IssueCompleted(object sender, IssueCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Resources.Add("SamlToken", e.Result);
    this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
}
```

The Silverlight app then puts the SAML token in the Authorization header of a request to my ASP.NET Web API services; again, using the same WSTrust implementation.

```cs
string uri ="https://localhost/WebApi/api/resource";
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
request.Method = "GET";

RequestSecurityTokenResponse rstr = (RequestSecurityTokenResponse)Application.Current.Resources["SamlToken"];
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "SAML " + rstr.RequestedSecurityToken.RawToken;

request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
{
    using (WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result))
    {
        // Process Response
    }
}, null);
```

First, am I going about this the right way? Second, if so, how do I get my ASP.NET Web API services to detect the SAML token and convert it into an `IClaimsPrincipal` server side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a Silverlight guru but there's a series of articles (and some custom classes) here regarding the WebAPI services and WIF - [ASP.NET WebAPI Security 1: Introducing   Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Http](http://leastprivilege.com/2012/03/07/asp-net-webapi-security-1-introducing-thinktecture-identitymodel-http/).

This may help?

Comment: Thank you. I have spent a lot of time on Dominick Baier's blog and he makes extensive use of his own Thinktecture framework but I could never find out how to do it myself. At least now I can inspect his source code and see what he did.